# react native useState Models in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have a model as I mentioned below and I have data related to this model, I want to print them as a result of comparison. but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I'm new to React Native.

models.js

```
export class Category {
  id: String;
  name: String;
  src: String;
  subCategories: String[];

  constructor(id: String, name: String, src: String, subCategories: String[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.src = src;
    this.subCategories = subCategories;
  }
}
```

data.js

```
export default [
{
        id: "1",
        name: "Tea",
        src: "https://cdn.domain.com/cat/551438_1619242670038.jpeg",
        subCategories: ["Bar"]

    }
    , {
        id: "2",
        name: "Dream",
        src: "https://cdn.domain.com/cat/551438_1619242670038.jpeg",
        subCategories: ["Hello", "Cat",]

    },
];
```

app.js

```
import Category from './models';
import CategoryData from './data';

function MainCategory() {
const [categories, setCategories] = useState();
return (
    <View>
      <View>
        {categories.map((item) => (
         
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you are getting data in  "CategoryData" , put it in  the useState(CategoryData), now you can use ma method or flatlist for data rendering

Comment: Can you write as an example?

Answer (score 1):

First of all declare your CategoryData in data.js like that.

```html
export default CategoryData =  [
    {
            id: "1",
            name: "Tea",
            src: "https://cdn.domain.com/cat/551438_1619242670038.jpeg",
            subCategories: ["Bar"]
    
        }
        , {
            id: "2",
            name: "Dream",
            src: "https://cdn.domain.com/cat/551438_1619242670038.jpeg",
            subCategories: ["Hello", "Cat",]
    
        },
    ];
```

And in app.js you just need to initialize your categories state like that.

```html
import Category from './models';
import CategoryData from './data';

function MainCategory() {
const [categories, setCategories] = useState(CategoryData);
return (
    <View>
      <View>
        {categories.map((item) => (
         
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, but what's the point of model?